# Javascript Not Implemented error

Tags: javascript

I am getting a Not Implemented error when trying to screen the screen-width into a hidden field on page load. Looking at other similar issues, they've all suggested putting everything in variables and making sure I wasn't using reserved words. I have and I am not (that I know of).

```
function GetScreenWidth() {
    var sWidth = screen.width;
    var hfSw = document.getElementById("<% =hfScreenWidth.ClientID %>");
    hfSw.value = sWidth;
}
window.onload = GetScreenWidth();
```

Originally, I was using

```
function GetScreenWidth() {
    document.getElementById("<% =hfScreenWidth.ClientID %>").value = screen.width;
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to get the screen-width back into the code-behind. If there are better ways to do that, I'd love to hear them.

**EDIT:**  the hidden field **is** defined above the  tag.

Comment: What browser are you using? What line is throwing the error? Is it a server error or a JavaScript error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this error message under IE when setting unexpected values to event handlers.  Basically, you're setting `onload` to a value of `undefined` (as that's what your function returns), which could cause all sorts of weird behavior.  You probably want to bind a reference to `GetScreenWidth` to the event handler, like so:

```
window.onload = GetScreenWidth;
```

Or perhaps:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var sWidth = screen.width;
    var hfSw = document.getElementById("<% =hfScreenWidth.ClientID %>");
    hfSw.value = sWidth;
};
```

Or, if you happen to be using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var sWidth = screen.width;
    var hfSw = document.getElementById("<% =hfScreenWidth.ClientID %>");
    hfSw.value = sWidth;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found this answer myself, but thanks. I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes, when it lets me.